# Can single Activity be used for multiple actions?

Tags: java, android

The cheat code app will have a list of games. And when each game is tapped, the cheat codes for that game will be displayed. My question is, do I have to create an activity for each game listed or is there a way to make it work in one activity.

Answer (score 2):

No you don’t need to make individual activity for each game listed rather you can go for a RecyclerView and fragments combination to make it work in one activity.

here i have added a recyclerView for the game list and the when items of the game list will be clicked then the recylerview will be hidden and the frameLayout id(content) will be populated with the fragment and when the back btn is pressed while inside the fragment reverse will happen( hiding the fragment and showing the recyclerView).

though this whole approach can be far more simplified if all the game have similar type of data to show then you can,
in that case you can pass data to the fragment and make it work with only one fragment.

hope this answer the question.

**

### XML code

**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

**

### Adapter code

**

```
public abstract class SettingsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SettingsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "SettingsAdapter";
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    private List<SettingData> data;

    public SettingsAdapter(Context context , List<SettingData> data){
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_settings_row, parent, false);
        SettingsAdapter.MyViewHolder holder = new SettingsAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        SettingData current = data.get(position);
        holder.settinsName.setText(current.settingName);
        holder.hostRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                OnButtonClicked(v, position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    protected abstract void OnButtonClicked(View v ,int position);

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView settinsName;
        private final RelativeLayout hostRelativeLayout;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            settinsName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.settings_name);
            hostRelativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hostRelativeLayout);
        }
    }
}
```

**

### android activity code inside onCreate

**

```
SettingsAdapter settingsAdapter = new SettingsAdapter(this, getFinalData()) {
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    protected void OnButtonClicked(View v, int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                settingsContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fab.show();
                configAppbarTittle(StudentSettingsActivity.this, settingNameArr[position]);
                appBarLayout.setExpanded(false);
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, new SavedPlacesFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                //similar
                break;
            case 2: 
                //similar
                break;
            case 3:
                //similar 
                break;
            default:
                break; 
        }

    }
};
settingsRecycleView.setAdapter(settingsAdapter);
settingsRecycleView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

**

### fragment code inside activity

**

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class SavedPlacesFragment extends Fragment {

    private StudentSettingsActivity myMainActivity;
    private RecyclerView savedPlacesRecycler;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        myMainActivity = (StudentSettingsActivity) getActivity();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //myMainActivity = (StudentSettingsActivity) getActivity();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stu_setting_saved_places_fragment, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    private void flush(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(myMainActivity, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            myMainActivity.fab.hide();
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), StudentSettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

> Please understand the fact that i have copy pasted from my production
>   code here. Just to demonstrate the way. If you copy paste this code it
>   won't work. You have to read through the code to understand the way
>   it's been implemented and then write it in your own way

Answer (score 0):

...You say that the cheat code app have list of games

You create one activity to show the list

....And if u tap on list to get new game

So you have to create fragment or activity to show the game by click on list

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single Activity and have it hold multiple fragments.
Your Activity ( Lets say MainActivity ) will be responsible for displaying fragments.
At a high level, you need 2 fragments:

> GameListFragment

- for displaying Game List and game item click. You will need a recycler view to display list of games on this fragment.

> GameCheatCodeDetailsFragment

- for displaying Cheat Code.

Refer to [SmartShows](https://github.com/SaurabhKukreja/SmartShows) to get some code reference.

Comment: I tried to refer and run the SmartShows but it has some error. Have checked it your shelf?

Comment: Not sure what error you might have encoutered. But you can refer it to get some code reference regarding how to create Activities and fragments the way you want it